# How to resolve javascript files conflict?

Tags: javascript, conflict

I am using two JS below in my master page :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script Src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </ script>
```

My problem is when I add the below JS file "1.10.3", one of my post back request sending two times.

But when I commented this JS "1.10.3" the multiple post back problem is resolve.And doing this,there is another javascript error is :-

```
"typeerror $(...).draggable is not a function"
```

And to resolve that error i have to include both the JS files.

Can anyone help me out on this ? I am working on ASP.NET MVC4.

Comment: Have you tried `$.noConflict();`??

Comment: Please post a code of your postback button.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the library, including it more than once could have undesired effects, because the functionality of JS may be conflicting. To avoid this add this code to your JavaScript Part.

```
<script>
    ...
    ...
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

For More info about `noConflict` : [**Click Here**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)