# How to resolve conflicting Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a modal and animation in an existing codepen template, but for some reason it's not working in an expected manner. Trying to figure it out, but not sure how to resolve the conflicts.

This is the existing [codepen](https://codepen.io/akapowl/pen/6a2480c123d88dc391faba0ea5cc590f) template that I'm trying to work on. This adds the parallax effect to the screen.

I added 2 buttons. (I'm using Twitter Bootstrap)

1. `Click Me` that would scroll the UI to the top - This does not work. Looks like there's some clash with the existing library because it works when tried otherwise. I'm unable to figure out the exact reason! This is what I've tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click-me').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

2. `Open Modal` that would open the modal - This opens up the modal, but `a)` the UI is broken and not selectable `b)` the modal opens up at the top, not at the current place.

This is what I've done. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/prafulbagai/pen/YzpxOaW) How can I resolve the conflicts?

I tried reading various SO questions but to no avail. [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978770/how-to-resolve-two-jquery-conflict) [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988729/how-to-resolve-javascript-files-conflict)

Comment: Just to point out, none of the jquery works on code pen you posted (and it is included), I tried using plain JS and got click  event to work on .click-me but then boomboom js throws errors on plain JS methods as console.log. I gave up in that point, you have to many libberys there included to study it all, try to re-arrange order of them, but doubt that will help.

Comment: How should I go about it? Any way forward? I want a similar parallax effect on my bootstrap webpage.

Comment: Any way forward?

Comment: Really don't know, im not big fan of using x amount of librarys on page, i dont even use bootstrap.  I write my own JS,. Maybe someone else will find solution.